# Is there a Windows command line tool to copy files to remote computers?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm looking for a way to copy files over to/from remote Windows hosts, and need to provide domain user credentials as part of the process, similar to the way `psexec` does.

I know I can use `net use` to map the target directory to a drive letter and use `xcopy`, and I know `psexec` can upload files to be executed on the remote machine and then delete them, but I'm looking for a way to distribute files to remote hosts that will not be as awkward to use as `net use` and `xcopy`.

Comment: why can't you use psexec if it does what you need?

Comment: it deletes the files afterwards, and it tries to execute them before that :-) i need to just transfer files around

Answer (score 18, accepted):

XCopy supports UNC paths.

```
C:\>xcopy \\computer1\source\*.* \\Computer2\target
C:\>xcopy \\computer1\source\FakeFileNAme.txt C:\
```

I would imagine with the use of RunAs you should be able to feed it whichever credentials you'd like.

HTH

Comment: FWIW, practically everything on Windows supports UNC paths - it is not xcopy-specific.

Comment: will runas allow me to use a user that cannot log on to the local machine to transfer files to the remote machine ?

Comment: I haven't used RunAs off a domain in quite a while, but I think the "RunAs /netonly" option will do what you're looking for.

Comment: what is the syntax for copying to a remote folder location, say to `C:\temp` of the remote computer? `xcopy .\local_file \\remote_computer\???` ?

Comment: I tried `xcopy .\local_file "\\10.220.x.x\c$\temp\` and I get "Invalid drive specification`

Answer (score 4):

You can use robocopy. just open a command window and type `robocopy /?` to see available options.

Comment: I didn't notice anything in robocopy for specifying credentials. Does it support that?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a "small utility", but the **pywin32** package of Python for Windows has [`win32net`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32net.html) and [`win32wnet`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32wnet.html) modules that could be helpful with scripting credentials and such.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question and answers, Powershell now supports remote copy.
See the documentation for [Copy-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item)
You may also need to [Enable PSRemoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting) (depending on your target machine)

> Example 5: Copy a file to a remote computer
>
> ```
> $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
> Copy-Item "D:\Folder001\test.log" -Destination "C:\Folder001_Copy\" -ToSession $Session
> ```

Comment: Copy-Item -Recurse FolderNameHere -Destination \\OtherMachine\C$\Temp