# copying files through command line in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

In my lab there are 70 windows systems is there . Each user has 1 system, in al systems C nd D are deniend .Eevry users should store their files in only Z drive. Now my question is I want to copy files from one user user to another user(we don't have access through pendrive). Please tell me how to copy files through command prompt or any other method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Windows command line tool to copy files to remote computers?](http://superuser.com/questions/120263/is-there-a-windows-command-line-tool-to-copy-files-to-remote-computers)

Comment: You need a shared file storage (a disk or directory) that both users can access, OR send them via email.